# setParams not setting parameter in apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

I have an aura component that passes a record Id to an apex controller to fetch records to display along with assessing a users permission to access the component. For reasons I cannot establish the ID as set from the force:hasRecordId attribute is not being passed to the apex controller.

The below is the part of the javascript controller that runs on load.

```
    initData: function(component) {

        var fetchRecordsAction = component.get('c.fetchRecords');
        fetchRecordsAction.setParams({
            rID : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        fetchRecordsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          //store state of response
          var state = response.getState();
          if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //set response value in wrapperList attribute on component.
            component.set('v.fmwList', response.getReturnValue());
            var fList = component.get("v.fmwList");
            if(fList.length==0){
                component.set('v.showMessageNone', 'true');
            }
          }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(fetchRecordsAction);

        var action = component.get('c.permissionToRun');
        action.setParams({ 
          rID : component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          //store state of response
          var state = response.getState();
          if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //set response value in wrapperList attribute on component.
            component.set('v.AllowAccess', response.getReturnValue());
          }
        });
        console.log(action);
        $A.enqueueAction(action);        
      }
```

The below is the mark up for the page (some logic in JS controller is not included as it is not relevant to the issue. The only issue really is with the passing of recordId to controller in init function.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasSObjectName" controller = "eSourcingFileMoverController">
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .cuf-content {
            padding: 0 0rem !important;
        }
        .slds-p-around--medium {
            padding: 0rem !important;
        }       
        .slds-modal__content{
            overflow-y:hidden !important;
            height:unset !important;
            max-height:unset !important;
            width:800px;
        }
    </aura:html>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initData}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fmwList" type="eSourcingFileMoverWrapper[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="folderList" type="eSourcingFileMoverLocationWrapper[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="showMessageNone" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showMessageNone2" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="AllowAccess" type="boolean" default="true"/>

    <aura:attribute name="CRef" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="CName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="FName" type="String" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.AllowAccess}">
        <div slot="header" style="text-align: center;margin-top: 10px">
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Move Files</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="one">
                <lightning:tab label="Select Files" id="one">
                    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                        Select the files you would like to move to a different folder. You can move files to one folder at a time. Click <b>"Find Folder"</b> to search for a folder and relocate the selected files.
                    </div> 
                    <div class="slds-p-around_medium" >              
                        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                                    <th scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Selected">Selected</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col">
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">File Name</div>
                                    </th>           
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.fmwList}" var="con">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                                <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkContact" value="{!con.selected}" />                                          
                                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
                                                <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="row">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" >{!con.Name}</div>
                                        </th>                   
                                    </tr>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>  
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showMessageNone}">
                            <ui:message title="Warning" severity="warning">
                                No Files Found
                        </ui:message>
                        </aura:if>            
                    </div>
                </lightning:tab>
                <lightning:tab label="Find Folder" id="two">
                    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                        You can search below for folders using any of the 3 search terms.
                    </div> 
                    <div class="slds-p-around_large">
                        <div class="slds-form_horizontal slds-form slds-grid slds-wrap" onkeyup="{!c.Search}">
                            <lightning:input class="slds-size_1-of-3"
                                aura:id="enter-search1"
                                name="enter-search-Ref"
                                label="Contract Ref"
                                type="search"
                            />
                            <lightning:input class="slds-size_1-of-3"
                                aura:id="enter-search2"
                                name="enter-search-CName"
                                label="Contract/ Project Name"
                                type="search"
                            />            
                            <lightning:input class="slds-size_1-of-3"
                                aura:id="enter-search3"
                                name="enter-search-FName"
                                label="Folder Name"
                                type="search"
                            /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.folderList))}">
                        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                            Press confirm to move any selected files to your selected folder.
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="slds-p-around_medium" >              
                            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Selected">Selected</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Contract</div>
                                        </th>   
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Folder Name</div>
                                        </th>                                                                                              
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.folderList}" var="con">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                                    <!--<ui:inputRadio name="others" value="{!con.selected}"/>-->     
                                                        <ui:inputCheckbox  value="{!con.selected}"/>                                                                                            
                                                    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
                                                    <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </th>
                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" >{!con.ContractName}</div>
                                            </th> 
                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" >{!con.Name}</div>
                                            </th>                                                                                                            
                                        </tr>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>  
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showMessageNone2}">
                                <ui:message title="Info" severity="warning">
                                    No Folders Found
                            </ui:message>
                            </aura:if>            
                        </div>
                    </aura:if>
                </lightning:tab>            
            </lightning:tabset>
        </div>
        <div slot="footer" class="slds-col modal-footer slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">Cancel</button>
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" label="Confirm" onclick="{!c.handleSelected}" />
        </div>  
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.AllowAccess}">
        <ui:message title="Access Denied" severity="error">
            You do not have the necessary permissions to proceed with this action. Please contact the record owner to amend your permissions to allow you to complete this action
    </ui:message>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

and this is the apex function that is being called:

```
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static boolean permissionToRun(Id rId){
        system.debug(rId);
        config_cs__c config = config_cs__c.getinstance();
        boolean allow = false;
        if(config.Enable_Team_Settings__c){
            boolean isSupplierFolder = true;
            String projectId;
            if(string.valueof(rId.getsobjecttype()).contains('Contract')){
                isSupplierFolder = false;
            }
            if(!isSupplierFolder){                    
                list<contract_document_folder__c> cdflist = [SELECT Id, Contract__c, Parent_Contract_Id__c FROM contract_document_folder__c WHERE Id = : rId];
                if(cdflist.size()>0){
                    projectId=cdflist[0].Parent_Contract_Id__c;
                }
            }
            else{
                list<supplier_documents_folder__c> sdflist = [SELECT Id, Contract__c FROM supplier_documents_folder__c WHERE Id = : rId];
                if(sdflist.size()>0){
                    projectId=sdflist[0].Contract__c;
                }                    
            }  
            //allow if approriate TSRs or owner
            list<proc_Contract__c> contlist = [SELECT Id, ownerId FROM proc_Contract__c WHERE Id = : projectId];
            if(contlist.size()>0){
                if(userinfo.getuserId()==contlist[0].ownerId){
                    allow=true;
                }
            }
            list<Procurement_Team__c> ptlist = [SELECT Id, Access_to_Shared_Document_Folders__c, Access_to_Contract_Documents__c FROM Procurement_Team__c WHERE  User__c = : userinfo.getuserId() and Contract__c = : projectId];              
            if(ptlist.size()>0){
                if(isSupplierFolder){
                    if(ptlist[0].Access_to_Shared_Document_Folders__c=='Full'){
                        allow=true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(ptlist[0].Access_to_Contract_Documents__c=='Full'){
                        allow=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            allow = true;
        }
        system.debug('allow---'+allow);
        return allow;
    }
```

when console logging the ID in JS I am seeing the ID logged there - however as soon as the value is debugged in the apex controller it reads as null.

I am at a loss for what the cause could be. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My wife solved it...

it was caching issue that meant I was chasing a ghost ending up one iteration wrong all the time.

rId was variable in apex and rID in js so there was a case sensitivity mismatch.